# Prism 6 WPF Create shell problem to override the onstartup class

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

How I can override the default startup class or windows if am using prism 6.
I went through the official docs of prism, but I could not find the expected answer.

I tried to derive the Application class from PrismApplication using Prims 6 but it was throwing me an error.

`public partial class App : PrismApplication {}`

as this was not happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use Bootstrapper class to initialize and Create the shell or startup window and then create a instance in startup method in app.xaml.cs

Bootstrapper.cs:

```
public class Bootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper
{
    protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
        // Resolve any instance here
        return Container.TryResolve<MainWindow>();
    }

    protected override void InitializeShell()
    {
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
    }
}
```

And then in App.xaml.cs file override the OnStartUp method and create this instance there and run the bootstrapper.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        var bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();
        bootstrapper.Run();
    }
}
```

**NOTE: StartUp attribute value should be removed from app.xaml file...**